# Dynamically change Facebook share thumbnail in ASP .Net

Tags: asp.net, facebook-graph-api

I used Facebook like button in ASP .Net my web site  master page and  when sharing page link in Facebook. I want to change the thumbnail attach with link to each pages, I get image url back end of my asp website and assign to variable and when I'm trying to bind it to front end as below it doesn't get actual value

```
<link rel="image_src" type="image/jpeg" href=" <% = ImgLink %>"/>
```

(ImgLink is dynamic variable I got from my back end of code )  at least it doesn't suggest in visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
    <link rel="image_src" type="image/jpeg" <%= "href='" + ImgLink + "'"%>/>
</asp:Placeholder>
```

[Here](http://csharpin.blogspot.ro/2011/11/saga-on-asp-net.html) is a detailed explanation why this is working.

Comment: when loading the page this exception occurred ""The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).""

Answer (score 1):

```
LitFacebook.Text = "<a name=\"fb_share\" type=\"button\" share_url =\"http://kidstrail.inoday.co.in/\"></a>" +
                   "<script " +
                   "src=\"http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share\" " +
                   "type=\"text/javascript\"></script>";
```

On Design Page, Take a Literal control:

```
<div style="float:left; height:18px; margin-left:3px; overflow:hidden;"><asp:Literal ID="LitFacebook" runat="server" ></asp:Literal> </div>
```